# Flutter After Upgrade can't run application version solving failed

Tags: flutter

Nope. [This answer doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375674/error-after-running-flutter-upgrade) this time for me.

My `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.5.9-pre.68, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 0.5.9-pre.68 at /home/khophi/.flutterSetup
    • Framework revision 5cd97f0004 (2 hours ago), 2018-08-16 14:10:22 -0700
    • Engine revision 4ee648914f
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/khophi/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/khophi/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.26.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 2.17.1

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • klte • 956e8b90 • android-arm • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

When I run `flutter run`, I get:

```
Running "flutter packages get" in townsquare...                  
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f.

Because flutter_circular_chart 0.0.3 requires SDK version >=1.19.0 <2.0.0 and no versions of flutter_circular_chart match >0.0.3 <0.1.0, flutter_circular_chart ^0.0.3 is forbidden.
So, because mobile depends on flutter_circular_chart ^0.0.3, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1)
```

This is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: mobile
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  carousel: ^0.0.1
  http: "^0.11.3+16"
  validate: "^1.6.0"
  url_launcher: "^3.0.2"
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.2"
  font_awesome_flutter: "^7.0.0"
  flutter_circular_chart: "^0.0.3"
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.3.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  assets:
   - images/flutter.jpg
   - images/logo.png
   - images/bg_viewer.jpg
```

With the above, please enlighten me, what's wrong?

Comment: Check it out: [Flutter 2 upgrade - Flutter version solving failed error](https://medium.com/@pratikbutani/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's is because you are using : `Dart version 2.1.0-dev.0.0.flutter-be6309690f` and the plugin named `flutter_circular_chart` has a `constraint`

https://github.com/xqwzts/flutter_circular_chart/blob/master/pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
   sdk: '>=1.19.0 <2.0.0'
```

You can fork the project and update the sdk constraint and ref to your repository:

Like this:

```
flutter_circular_chart:
    git: https://github.com/your_repo/flutter_circular_chart.git
```

**Note**
Also would be fine if you open an issue in their repo to notify the devs about the issue that you have.

Comment: What about multiple plugins dependency?... one cant be forking every repo in order to modify them...

Comment: yeah that is something that plugin developers have to take in mind, I mean keeping the plugin updated or the community could help with it.

Comment: updating SDK version not fixing my version solving issue while I using date picker dropdown plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use devendency_override with same version witch need for same for other dependency.

Like  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1 needs intl to be 0.16.0

then craete dependency_overrides:
intl: ^0.16.0

below of dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

run project until it not run on device.

Enjoy. Thanks..