# Version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart

Suddenly in project I got an error 'import js.dart' or smth like that. I found a command tip 'flutter channel beta' so I changed, upgraded, and after that nothing works.

When I run any command in flutter I get error:

```
Building flutter tool...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.0-0.0.dev.flutter-a3815b6590.

Because flutter_tools depends on collection >=1.15.0-nnbd <1.15.0-nullsafety.2 which
  requires SDK version >=2.9.0-18.0 <=2.9.10, version solving failed.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter After Upgrade can't run application version solving failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886318/flutter-after-upgrade-cant-run-application-version-solving-failed)

Comment: Hello, it doesn't because I don't use this plugin and not only none of app can run, I can't even use any command

Comment: Have you tried upgrading flutter?

Comment: Yes, but now this and every other command gives me error from quest

Comment: So maybe try downgrading it then. See this github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62146

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem

Answer (score 3):

I just cd to flutter root folder then "git pull origin --ff-only", finally type "flutter upgrade".